# Per-user total traffic counter

Tags: logs, traffic

How can I get a per-user traffic counter?

(I'm not looking for real-time monitoring such as `nethogs`)

---

`ifconfig` displays a traffic counter for all users:

[image]

[UserIPacct](http://ramses.smeyers.be/homepage/useripacct/#description) isn't maintained anymore.

Comment: found a similar thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/28926/how-to-monitor-network-bandwidth-per-user-on-ubuntu-server